# File 'sample.docx' is corrupt therefore can't be opened, cause due to of document manipulation or damage due to data transmission, using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, mono

After lots of debug, I am able to find out about size discrepancy between the document size.

Actually, I am trying to send `.docx` file to client-end, here is my `C#` block code look as

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(documentFilePath);
byte[] fileConent = File.ReadAllBytes(documentFilePath);
Console.WriteLine("Byte Length :" + fileConent.Length);

context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", file.Name));
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileConent);
context.Response.End();
```

Output of above code gives the document file size as follows

```
Byte Length :4338
```

Here is client-end code to download `.docx` file as follows

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/exportDataForDocument,
    data: JSON.stringify(result),
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        var fileName = "sample.docx";
        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" });
        console.log("Byte length of the Blob: " + blob.size + " bytes");

        //Check the Browser type and download the File.
        var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;
        if(isIE) {
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
        } else {
            var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            link = url.createObjectURL(blob);
            var a_down = $("<a />");
            a_down.attr("download", fileName);
            a_down.attr("href", link);
            $("body").append(a_down);
            a_down[0].click();
            a_down.remove();
        }
    }
},
```

Above `JS` block gives the byte size for downloading document file

```
Byte length of the Blob: 7045 bytes
```

Due to size discrepancy between the document size on the server and the document size received on the client side, I am not getting the same document, instead receiving the corrupt document from server.

Not sure, why document size change on client-side?

Comment: Instead of providing the solution peoples tends to devote this question. It looks to me some people here to raise its badge. Plz, try to understand here that I have tried every possible solution but I didn't get success to achieve the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of struggle, I was finally able to resolve the problem and download the `.docx` file from the server.

Done a few changes on server code as below:

```
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", documentFileName));
context.Response.AppendHeader("X-Request-URL", context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
context.Response.TransmitFile(documentFilePath);
context.Response.Flush();
context.Response.End();
```

And done few changes on front-end code as follows:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: '/exportDataForDocument,
 data: JSON.stringify(result),
 xhrFields: {
     responseType: 'blob'
 },
 success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
     var contentDisposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
     var fileName = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition').split("filename=")[1];
     
     var a = document.createElement('a');
     var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
     var objectUrl = url.createObjectURL(data);
     a.style.display = 'none';
     a.href = objectUrl;
     a.download = fileName;
     document.body.appendChild(a);
     a.click();
     document.body.removeChild(a);
     url.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);        
 },
 error: function(e) {
     console.log(e)
 }
});
```

Lastly, I am able download a proper & correct with same size of `.docx` file from server.